# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32, trying to make it so the user can delete a record

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to make it so the user can enter the ID of a record into a textbox and once a button is pressed, the record which has that ID is deleted from the database, but this error occurs. Is this a matter of changing the command text?

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    con.Open()
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("DELETEFROM tblInvoices WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID", con)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("InvoiceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TblMaterials WHERE MaterialID = @MaterialID", con)
    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@MaterialID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Dim cmd3 As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblPayments WHERE PaymentID = @PaymentID", con)
    cmd3.Parameters.Add("@PaymentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3.Text
    Dim cmd4 As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblSupplier WHERE SupplierID = @SupplierID", con)
    cmd4.Parameters.Add("SupplierID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox3.Text
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Besides the issue with your input, you are missing a space in `DELETEFROM` in the first  SQL statement and you are missing the `@` prefix on the first and last parameter names.

Comment: Given that `SqlClient` supports multiple SQL statements per command, you only need one command and one parameter. You can just separate the statements with semicolons and use the same parameter name in each one, e.g. `DELETE FROM tblInvoices WHERE InvoiceID = @ID; DELETE FROM tblMaterials WHERE MaterialID = @ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try sample below, obviously you may want dome error trapping

cmd4.Parameters.Add("SupplierID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cint(TextBox3.Text)

Answer (score 0):

TextBox3.Text is a string. You are passing the string in as the ID which is an Int32. You have to convert it to an integer.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    con.Open()
    Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblInvoices WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;DELETE FROM TblMaterials WHERE MaterialID = @MaterialID;DELETE FROM tblPayments WHERE PaymentID = @PaymentID;DELETE FROM tblSupplier WHERE SupplierID = @SupplierID", con)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.toInt32(TextBox3.Text)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@MaterialID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.toInt32(TextBox3.Text)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@PaymentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.toInt32(TextBox3.Text)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.toInt32(TextBox3.Text)
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Also you should validate input in TextBox3. Maybe write a function that checks if the text entered only has numbers inside it and it's not over the 32 bit limit.

Comment: I tried that but a new error came up "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: What was in textbox3?

Comment: Also your sql parameters are also wrong. Check the comments on your question.

Comment: Yeah I figured my sql paramters were wrong but the error still comes up. I am entering 1 into the textbox

Comment: @C2W Also please check the table names. One of your tables is written with a capital T is that correct?

Comment: @C2W Did this work? I tried it out and it worked for me. If not you should post all functions referencing to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be converting the `String` from the `Text` of the `TextBox` to an `Integer`, given that that is what you're specifying the type of the parameter as. That said, it should still convert implicitly if the `String` contains a valid number. What is the value of `TextBox3.Text` when that happens? Presumably it is not a number. You should be validating and converting the user data before using it, which you would do using `Integer.TryParse`.

Comment: Well I'm trying to delete a record with ID 1 so I enter 1 into the text box

Comment: You clearly think you are but you're not or you wouldn't see that error. Did you debug your code, I'd wager not. If you use `Integer.TryParse` then it will work when the data is valid and won't crash when it's not. If you debug properly you'll be able to see when and why the data is invalid.